# What is the best plastic to make a see through 'whiteboard' with?

Tags: garage

Over the past few months I've slowly been converting my garage into a DIY/project/man zone by adding lighting, work benches, storage and tools.

Next I'd like to mount a piece of transparent plastic to the wall to use as a 'whiteboard'

I know that I'd like to use a plastic, rather than glass, so that it wont easily shatter and will have more give to it.

Other than that I'd like a material that I can draw on and wipe clean, won't flex too much  when I write on it and be as cheap as possible (whilst being up to the task)

Suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be transparent?

Comment: I'd like to see my garage wall through it. So really just my personal asthestics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Markee Dry-Erase Paint](http://www.dryerasemagic.com/) is clear, so it won't even look like you've got a dry erase surface at all. You may want to put up an outline though, since I could see running off the edge of the painted surface being a problem. It's also a bit pricey, at $59/quart or $127/gal. (I haven't used this product myself, so no guarantees on how well it works.)

Another option is [Opti-White](http://mywhiteboards.com/optirite.html) dry erase film, also in clear. It's $26/ft for a 5' wide sheet. (So a 3'x5' sheet will run you $78 - it would be cheaper to go with the paint-on option, unless you don't want to deal with the mess.)

If you want to go the 'board' route instead of a wall covering, you could try [Lexan](http://www.lowes.com/pd_239982-1638-1PC0036A_0__?productId=3142233&Ntt=lexan&pl=1&currentURL=/pl__0__s%3FNtt%3Dlexan). It's fairly lightweight and you should be able to get it at most home improvement stores. Lowes has it for about $70 for a 3'x4' sheet.

Comment: With Dry-Erase paint you need to have a very smooth surface or it will not work very well (or you need to apply a lot of coats to form the smooth surface).  Notice the Markee Dry-Erase paint mentions to apply 8-10 coats (this is so any bumps are smoothed out)... your garage wall might need more.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've decided to go the Lexan route. I've ordered a 900mm x 600mm x 4mm off eBay for £30. Fingers crossed it works out

Comment: @Peter: I'm sure the other SE users would love to see the finished product. Post pics if you get the chance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into 30 Gauge Polished Marine Vinyl Outdoor Boat Automotive. It's easy to place, very cheap, and little to no damage if wanting to take down.