# What easily obtained material would work best to protect my LCD screen?

Tags: materials

I've got 18 month and 2 1/2 year old boys. I'm considering purchasing a TV, and I'm concerned about the occasional lapse in judgement. (e.g.: The odd toy being thrown at the screen in a fit of uncontrolled anger) What material would be easiest and ideal for protecting my 46"-55" screen from infrequent projectiles. (I'm not expecting it to have to take a huge beating, but it should be able to deflect a pen or maybe a matchbox car)

The clearer the better, but my guess is I can get rid of the protector in 18 months or so anyway, so this is not a permanent solution.

[I've seen the following,](http://www.tv-armor.com/shop/standard-tv-screen-protector-c-1) but was hoping to get in a little cheaper (particularly since the 55" version is $240)

[I'm considering a basic acrylic](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&productId=100250108&R=100250108), but not sure if this is the **best** choice or not.

Comment: I've worked with acrylic, but never trying to cut pieces that large ... I'd be inclined to get it cut at the hardware store if you can, as it took me a few tries to figure out how deep I had to score it before cracking so I'd get a straight break. (if it break to the side, if it's larger than what you need, it's really hard to clean up the edge ... if large, you can try a brake for bending sheet metal, but a lot of sanding is generally best.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a sheet of [Polycarbonate Lexan](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=lexan+sheets&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=3274414078451318565&ei=h5NSTaCZC4ep8Aa-rryiCg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDEQ8wIwAQ#), It will stand up well to projectiles.

When you no longer need it, you could convert it into a [whiteboard](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/best-way-to-light-a-lexan-polycarbonate-sheet) as @Peter Bridger did.

Answer (score 3):

Go with Acrylic, as you suggested yourself.  It's cheap, durable, flexible and easy to clean.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you used acrylic (or any other coating) yourself? I'm not doubting your answer, but I'd be interested in any personal experience you may have had.

Comment: Not for this particular type of application.  But I have used it before for windows, and it is very easy to work with.

Comment: +1 I liked both answers, it strikes me that this line was indeed unanswerable. I thought there might be some incontrovertible fact which swayed the answer in one direction or another, but it turns out no.